# jQuery Mobile - Popup in nested list view

Tags: jquery-mobile

I try to create a listview where elements with no children can have an edit button. When the user clicks to this button a popup menu should appear.

[image]

Here is the code inside a singe JQM page.

```html
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <h3>Colors</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Blue
                <p class="edit">
                    <a href="#" onclick="openEditMenu()" data-role="button"
                        data-icon="gear" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">Edit</a>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>Orange</li>
            <li>Purple</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><h3>Item</h3>
        <p class="edit">
            <a href="#" onclick="openEditMenu()" data-role="button"
                data-icon="gear" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">Edit</a>
        </p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
            <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Edit Element</li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            ...
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    function openEditMenu() {
        $('#popupMenu').popup('open');
    }
</script>
```

On the first level this works like expected. If you navigate to the second level of the nested list, the popup is not shown.

I saw that popups in JQM has to be placed on the same page. It seems that JQM does not find the popup on the subpages of the listview.

Has somebody realized successfully such a solution or it is not possible with the popup feature of JQM 1.2?

[On jsfiddle you can find my example code.](http://jsfiddle.net/ynqjw/2/)

Thanks for tipps or suggestions.

Comment: If you inspect the popup div it is enabled (given a width and height) in the HTML, but still not shown...

Comment: If i take a look at the DOM when the page is loaded. JQM has created a new page with the `data-url="home&ui-page=0-0"` So then when You switch to the subpage and click to the button, the popup changes correct its visibility but is not shown. I suggest it is because it is on the "home" page not the active page.
In the JQM documentation there is a notice _A popup div has to be nested inside the same page as the link._ So it is now clearer for me why this is not working.
Maybe someone has an idea how this could be realized to place or generate a popup div for every of this dynamic subpages.

Comment: there is one plugin called action sheet in jquery mobile . U may try that.this is link to that https://github.com/hiroprotagonist/jquery.mobile.actionsheet                    action sheet have similar work and better UI that popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in the comments above, from the jQm documentation '*A popup div has to be nested inside the same page as the link.*'.

What you could try is clone the popup and attach it to the other page. Then you have re-initialize and open it.
You could try something like:

```
var nestedLiPage = $(".ui-page-active");
$('#popupMenu').clone().appendTo(nestedLiPage).popup().popup('open');
```

Answer (score -1):

[Solved]

http://jsfiddle.net/F9awk/

```
function openEditMenu() {
  var nestedLiPage = $(".ui-page-active");
  $('#popupMenu').clone().appendTo(nestedLiPage).popup().popup('open');
}
```